# What are "liquor rounds"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

From the movie *Wanted*:

A woman accosts a man at a pharmacy.

> Woman: I knew your father.
>
> Man: My father left the week I was born, so ...
>
> Woman: Your father died yesterday on the rooftop of the Metropolitan Building. Sorry.
>
> Man: (scoffs) Look, the **liquor rounds** are just over there, so ...

I first through he's talking about "rounds of liquor", but it appears here he is referring to a liquor store. What is "liquor rounds"? It doesn't appear idiomatic with my limited Google-fu.

Comment: Perhaps in the pharmacological sense of "pills", benzodiazepine and similar, for treament of alcohol withdrawal syndrome?

Comment: How does the conversation evolve after the last remark you quoted? You have not provided the full context. Also, do you have a link to the conversation in a video?

Comment: What he actually says (thank's to Rob's link to the video clip) is **Look, the liquor round's just over there**.  The verb is not plural.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Now that you clarifies it, it does sound like singular in the movie. My bad. I got the lines from a subtitles file.

Comment: Maybe **rounds** is what the script had and what he was supposed to say. His accent changes-- the line sounds bungled to me. But since it's followed by a shoot-em-up sequence, it didn't really matter.  The bullet going through an aisle-long array of breakfast cereal boxes was a nice comic effect.

Answer (score 1):

A [PET liquor round](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pet%20liquor%20round%22) is liquor industry term for a round plastic bottle, often a large bottle of 1.75 liters (PET is Polyethylene terephthalate - a very common plastic).

Presumably this movie is set in a place where it it legal for pharmacies to also sell liquor, and the man is implying that this woman is a drunk who probably would be happier (and less annoying to him) if she just drank a bunch of alcohol.

Comment: I don't see how your interpretation is absolutely correct, or an improvement over mine. Yours is 'get lost over there (not far away)' and mine is 'get lost, go find your friends at the bar'. - Time will (may?) tell. I'll see if I can track down better context.

Comment: @Rob CY's answer is superior because he actually explains what a _round_ is.  I've been speaking English for a very long time and had no idea what a round was.  Based on usage, I believe your definition of _round_ is incorrect.

Comment: @EllieK It's "rounds" and not "round", the difference being is that "making the rounds" probably doesn't mean you are the bartender (but it could). Whereas roundS is traveling and that's what he wants her to do.

Answer (score 0):

> "Man: (scoffs) Look, the **liquor rounds** are just over there, so ..."

Man: (scoffs) Look, the [pub crawl route](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub_crawl#Background) is just over there, so ...

Intended meaning: You are a [drunkard](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/drunkard) whom has lost their way, go look for someone your equal at the drinking contest and share your thoughts with them.

Dictionary.com definition: [bar-hopping](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bar-hopping)

> "Informal - To go to a succession of bars or nightclubs, with a brief stay at each.".

Collins Dictionary: [bar-hopping](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bar-hop):

> "Intransitive verb - If a person bar-hops, they go from one bar to another having drinks in each one.
>
> [US] informal - A yearly rite-of-passage in which graduating seniors bar-hop from morning until late afternoon.".

---

Derived from:

[liquor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/liquor) - Cambridge  Dictionary:

> "noun - An alcoholic drink, esp. one that has been distilled (= heated to a gas, then cooled to a liquid)".

[rounds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rounds) - Cambridge Dictionary:

> "plural noun - A work activity that regularly involves going to several different places".

Here's a [transcript of the movie](https://lingualeo.com/es/jungle/clip-wanted-grocery-store-shootout-190744#/page/1) and a [video clip of that conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2pzOimT9so).

Comment: Makes sense, but I'd like to see another example of its use. Is "round" used in that sense in US English (a web search for "paper round" only found examples of it use on uk and au websites

Comment: @JamesK - Because it's tagged [meaning] and [meaning-in-context] there aren't readily available examples. If you search the first link's words "[pub crawl route](https://www.google.com/search?q=pub+crawl+route)" the *practice* is common, though the insult may not be. --- An example from [TheFashionSpot](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lubricated+with+generous+liquor+rounds%22&oq=%22lubricated+with+generous+liquor+rounds%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.12...5589.11159.0.12234.3.3.0.0.0.0.113.282.1j2.3.0....0...1c.1j4.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..2.1.112.FbOu2IRU1mA).

Comment: My question was on the use of the word "round". I'm aware of its use in UK English  "a milk round", "a paper round", "do the rounds of the local job agencies" etc.  but that meaning is slightly distinct from the example. I'd like to see an example of round being used as in the example.

Comment: I think you are incorrect. A "liquor round" is an industry term for a type of bottle, usually a large one. I've added my own answer.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - I've added a transcript and a video clip of that portion of the movie. There is nothing that supports your position. The flippant interjection and random direction pointing indicates that he wasn't pointing out something in the store. He wants her to leave the uncomfortable conversation she thrust upon him.

Comment: And let's not forget _round_ used to indicate one drink for every member of a group of people, as in, "I bought a round for everyone at the bar."  But based on context that definition doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: @Rob - On the other hand, you can see that behind him there's a produce section and full aisles of groceries, so the store isn't just a pharmacy, it's a supermarket.  In many US states, supermarkets sell liquor (in liquor rounds, even).  Very few supermarkets host pub crawls. [Note: your link to a transcript doesn't actually point to a transcript, just to the video again.]

Comment: @CanadianYankee - " Very few supermarkets host pub crawls.", seems likely; your point? --- When she thrusts herself randomly into his life, says she knows his father and he's dead you propose that he wants her to go away and get lost, but not too far away. When someone tells you to get lost it doesn't mean to stick around. In her case she has a machine pistol and is there to save him from an assassin, she's not going anywhere. BTW: Fixed the transcript, it was part of the link from the prior edit.

Comment: @Rob - Okay, I've liked to examples in the real world where "liquor rounds" means "plastic bottles of liquor."  Can you provide any examples in the real world where "liquor rounds" means "pub crawl"?